# Python GTK3 - TreeView not being updated properly

Tags: python, multithreading, treeview, gtk3

I have issue with GTK's TreeView with ListStore. Records are updated, but sometime only when I hover it.
Bigger problem are new records - It's like it stops to displaying new ones unless I scroll to bottom all the time - which is weird.

I use Glade.
My code (slightly simplified)

```
class UI(SampleUI):
  gladefile = 'ui.glade'
  iterdict = {}

  def __init__(self, module):
    super().__init__(module)

  def start(self):
    self.fetch_widgets()
    self.connect_events()
    self.window.show()

  def fetch_widgets(self):
    self.window = self.builder.get_object('window')
    self.liststore = self.builder.get_object('store')

  def connect_events(self):
    handlers = {
        "on_window_close"  : Gtk.main_quit,
        "on_start_working": self.start_working,
        "on_stop_working": self.stop_working
    }
    self.builder.connect_signals(handlers)

    self.module.url_pending_action = self.url_pending
    self.module.url_succeed_action = self.url_update

  def start_working(self, button):
    self.module.start()

  def stop_stop(self, button):
    self.module.stop()

  def url_pending(self, data):
    self.iterdict[data['url']] = self.liststore.append([0, data['url'], 0, '', data['text']])

  def url_update(self, data):
    _iter = self.iterdict[data['url']]
    self.liststore[_iter][1] = data['some_field1']
    self.liststore[_iter][2] = data['some_field2']
```

Methods self.url_pending and self.url_update are called by threads (at most 30 running at the same time) created in self.module

I checked and new records are correctly appended into ListStore - I can read data from it. Window is working fine, but there are no new items at the bottom.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I made research and I figured out that GTK don't like being called from outside of main thread.

There was methods in Gdk to lock GTK calls

```
Gtk.threads_enter()
...
Gtk.threads_leave()
```

But now it's deprecated and GTK documentation says that every GTK call should be in main thread.

My workaround:

```
# [...]

def start(self):
  # [...]
  GObject.timeout_add(100, self.query_do)

# [...]

def query_do(self):
  while len(self.gtk_calls):
    self.gtk_calls.pop()()
  GObject.timeout_add(100, self.query_do)
```

And I'm just adding into query

```
self.gtk_calls.insert(0, lambda: anything())
```

The code isn't as clear as it was before, but works perfect.

Comment: You should probably use [`Gdk.threads_add_idle`](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gdk-3.0/functions.html#Gdk.threads_add_idle) instead of `GObject.timeout_add`, but otherwise this is the right idea.